# I am trying to change a string value with a onClick method in a .NET api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So, i have this button that redirects the user to a checkout page. In it I want to define a string from the clicked button. In this case it needs to be "custom"

```
<button class="btn btn-style" type="submit" id="cOrder">Order</button>
<script>
document.getElementById("cOrder").onclick = function() { 
    @{
        PizzaModel model = new PizzaModel();
        model.Pizza.PizzaName = "Custom";
    }
} 
</sript>
```

but I keep getting a System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

this Pizza name is defined on a Model class and I want to use it on the checkout page so the user can see what he ordered

I have this model PizzasModel:

```
public class PizzasModel
{
    public string PizzaName { get; set; }
    public float PizzaPrice { get; set; }
    public string Adress { get; set; }
    public string Payment { get; set; }
    public bool Cheese { get; set; }
    public bool Mushroom { get; set; }
    public bool Pepperoni { get; set; }
    public bool Pinaple { get; set; }
    public bool Sauce { get; set; }
    public bool Tomato { get; set; }
}
```

which is consumed by the PizzaModel (Pizza.cshtml) generated by .NET

```
public class PizzaModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public PizzasModel Pizza { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        return RedirectToPage("/Checkout/Checkout", new {Pizza.PizzaName, Pizza.PizzaPrice});
    }
}
```

The OnPost method uses the form that my button is inserted

```
<form method="post">

                  <div class="toppigns-items">
                      <label for="Ch">Cheese</label>
                      <input class="check" type="checkbox" id="Ch" name="topping" value="Ch" asp-for="Pizza.Cheese">
                  </div>
                  <div class="toppigns-items">
                       <label for="Mu">Mushroom</label>
                       <input class="check" type="checkbox" id="Mu" name="topping" value="Mu" asp-for="Pizza.Mushroom">
                  </div>
                  <div class="toppigns-items">
                       <label for="Pe">Pepperoni</label>
                       <input class="check" type="checkbox" id="Pe" name="topping" value="Pe" asp-for="Pizza.Pepperoni">
                  </div>
                  <div class="toppigns-items">
                      <label for="Pi">Pinaple</label>
                      <input class="check" type="checkbox" id="Pi" name="topping" value="Pi" asp-for="Pizza.Pinaple">
                  </div>
                  <div class="toppigns-items">
                      <label for="Sa">Sauce</label>
                      <input class="check" type="checkbox" id="Sa" name="topping" value="Sa" asp-for="Pizza.Sauce">
                  </div>
                  <div class="toppigns-items">
                      <label class="lCheck" for="To">Tomato</label>
                      <input type="checkbox" id="To" name="topping" value="To" asp-for="Pizza.Tomato">
                  </div>
                  <hr />
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-style" type="submit" id="cOrder">Order</button>                 
              </form>
```

And finally is used on my checkout page, where will be displayed some atrributes

```
<div>
    <p>1 @Model.PizzaName</p>
    <p>Total: U$@Model.PizzaPrice</p>
</div>
```

[What I am trying to do is set PizzaName by the button clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuLsd.jpg)

Comment: And what exactly is a `PizzaModel`? What does the `PizzaModel` constructor do? We can guess, but without the details of what `PizzaModel` is and what the `Pizza` property is, odds on we can't help you beyond general troubleshooting tips... and that's not what this site is for.

Comment: No you cannot create the object of  `C# class` inside the `<script>` section. Firstly you have to create this object within the  `@{}`  that's outside of `<script>` then pass it to there and finally to API that would work what you are trying to. In addition please share you full code snippet along with what you you are trying to implement.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I updated the question with those informations

Comment: @Corey I updated the question with those informations

Answer (score 0):

The first issue, the one that causes the exception you're getting, is because the `PizzaModel.Pizza` property isn't initialized, so it has the default value of `null`. When you try to set a property using `model.Pizza.PizzaName = "Custom";` there is no object for the value to apply to.

To fix this you need to create and assign a instance of `PizzasModel` to the `Pizza` property. You can either do this in the `PizzaModel` class or during object creation.

Option one:

```cs
public class PizzaModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public PizzasModel Pizza { get; set; } = new PizzasModel();
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        return RedirectToPage("/Checkout/Checkout", new {Pizza.PizzaName, Pizza.PizzaPrice});
    }
}
```

Option two (combining initialization of the PizzaName property):

```cs
PizzaModel model = new PizzaModel 
{ 
    Pizza = new PizzasModel
    {
        PizzaName = "Custom",
    }
};
```

The next problem is that you can't mix javascript and C# code that way. C# code in `@{ }` blocks will execute on the server during page generation, before the HTML for the page is transmitted to the client. The object you create in that code are server-side only and not accessible to the client in any way, and they will be elegible for garbage collection as soon as page generation completes.

On the client side your script looks like this:

```js
<script>
document.getElementById("cOrder").onclick = function() { 
} 
</sript>
```

If you want things to happen on the client you need to either write them as javascript or write some dynamic page code that interfaces with C# code on the server side. There are various libraries around that facilitate this kind of thing depending on what you're after, but they all run server side with all of the communications delays and so on. Better to handle the client-side stuff directly unless it actually requires server-side functionality.

In this case it seems like you're wanting to browse to a new page. In that case all you need is a way to pass the appropriate data to the server during the page fetch. For small amounts of non-sensitive data you can just add it to the query string - `https://server/page?PizzaName=Custom` for instance. For more complex data a form is often simpler:

```html
<form method="post" id="theForm" action="page" style="display:none">
  <input asp-for="Pizza.PizzaName" type="hidden" id="PizzaName" />
  <input asp-for="Pizza.Cheese" type="hidden" />
  <input asp-for="Pizza.Pepperoni" type="hidden" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("cOrder").onclick = function() { 
    document.getElementById("PizzaName").value = "Custom";
    document.getElementById("theForm").submit();
  }
</script>
```

In the `OnPost()` method the `Pizza` property will be filled with values from the form, but you'll want to initialize it in `OnGet()` or potentially face the wrath of the `NullReferenceException`.

There are numerous variations on the theme, including constructing the form's `input` elements during click and so on. Or just go ahead and put an actual visible form in the page and post from that.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to fix my code and now it's working as I want!
I do have some interpretations to confirm.
The type="hidden" creates an element of my form that doesn't appear on the screen, and then the asp-for makes what pass inside that element be the value of PizzaName OnPost?

Comment: @ArthurBorges `asp-for` is a helper that fills in the `name` and `value` attributes automatically from the expression you pass it. When the form is posted the ASP.NET framework fills in your model from the form data before calling `OnPost()`. If you look at the HTML source you'll see something like `<input name="Pizza.PizzaName" value="false" type="hidden" />`... with a couple of other attributes depending on the input type. Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms#the-input-tag-helper).